# How to make a combobox in a yatzy game in C# Visual Studio on Mac

Tags: c#, combobox

How do I make a ComboBox of possible dice choices in a Yatzy game in C# Visual studio on Mac?

I have made a foreach loop, where I use a switch case to test the points of ones, twos, threes etc. with the available fields on the point pad.

In the GUI, I want the ComboBox to show all the possible choices, so when I have rolled the dices, I can choose which dice combination I want, and it will write the result/points in the correct field in the GUI.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. please provide code and more description.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] of your progress so far.